# Grails app on Cloudfoundry: RhinoScriptEngineFactory not found

Tags: grails, rhino, cloud-foundry

In my grails application, I needed to execute some javascript (not JSON) fetched from a remote server:

```
new javax.script.ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("javascript")
```

But got the error: **RhinoScriptEngineFactory not found**.

I would assumed that RhinoScriptEngineFactory (JSR 223) is included in JDK/JRE. Am I wrong? Does anybody knows the proper way to add Javascript support to a Cloudfoundry application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it should work if you stage the application using the java7 runtime flag, e.g

```
vmc push grails-hello --path=target/hello-world-0.1.war --runtime=java7
```

You can see an example running at http://grails-hello.cloudfoundry.com/hello/index with the following code in the controller;

```
package hello.world
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;

class HelloController 
{
  def index() 
  { 
      ScriptEngine engine = new javax.script.ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("javascript");
      render "hello world (" + engine.toString() + ")";
  }
}
```

Comment: java7 runtime does it. Thank a lot

Comment: that's great, np. If you could mark the question as answered and vote it up that would be awesome!